# Play sound in react-js

Tags: javascript, audio, reactjs, media, wav

I try to play a sound on react-js but I can't make it start.
I have my sound var initialised in my reactClass, before get InitialState:

```
var App = React.createClass({
audio: new Audio('files/audio.mp3'),
getInitialState: function () {
return {
  playSound: false,
   ........
 }
}
```

And this are the functions that I have for start and stop:

```
   playSound: function() {
if(!this.state.playSound){
    this.setState({
        playSound: true,
    }, function(){
      console.log("play sound 1");
      this.audio.play();
      console.log("play sound 2");
    });
}
},

stopSound: function() {
if(this.state.playSound){
    this.setState({
        playSound: false,
    }, function(){
        console.log("stop sound 1");
        this.audio.pause();
        console.log("stop sound 2");
    });
}
},
```

But I  get back this answer:

```
react-app.js:346 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The element has no supported sources.
```

I have tried both with a .mp3 and .wav file. but it won't start. What am I doing wrong?

!!!! EDIT:
Also tried adding a HTML item:

```
  <audio id="beep" loop>
         <source src="files/ring.wav" type="audio/wav" />
      </audio>
```

And with the following start/stop:

```
  playSound: function() {
if(!this.state.playSound){
    this.setState({
        playSound: true,
    }, function(){
      console.log("play sound 1");
      var audioElement = document.getElementById('beep');
      audioElement.setAttribute("preload", "auto");
      audioElement.autobuffer = true;
      audioElement.load();
      audioElement.play();
      console.log("play sound 2");
    });
}
},

stopSound: function() {
if(this.state.playSound){
    this.setState({
        playSound: false,
    }, function(){
        console.log("stop sound 1");
        var audioElement = document.getElementById('beep');
        audioElement.pause();
        console.log("stop sound 2");
    });
}
},
```

Then I get no error on start, but it doesn't start. When I press pause I get:

```
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The play() request was interrupted by a call to pause().
```

!!!! EDIT2:

Also I noticed, that if I set buttons, to play the sound. If I open the file manager, go to my index.html and open it, it works perfectly. If I try the page from the webpack-server: localhost:8000/app/index.html, it won't work. getting the same DOMException. why is this?

Comment: Can I ask where are you calling playSound() from - Render or an another React lifecycle method?

Comment: Well, it's a bit more complex. But I have a react-app.js Class, which is the main index.html, and has tabs, and A View in which I render my Pages.
I initialize a C++ library, that has a callback function, and when I change stuff in native, I get back callbacks, and from there I was playing the sound. I fixed the issues, it was pretty simple, now that I think about it, I will add the response now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After trying for a while, I made 2 buttons, 1 to start the sound and one to stop, in my index.html file. So I tried that, and I noticed that it works from my file manager, but not if I try from the webpack server.
So I checked my paths, and instead of:
"files/audio.mp3" I changed it to "../files/audio.mp3". A rookie mistake, but that's what happens when you put a Android developer to work in javascript :)))