# How to play a wav (loaded from a URL) in React/html5?

Tags: reactjs, html5-audio, wav

I want to include an audio player that plays a wav file that is loaded from a URL in a React component. Although this should work straight forward with the HTML5 `<audio>` element, I cannot get it to play (I just see the control elements).

I tried to play a .mp3 with the same code, which works. I checked in Chrome and Safari which are supposed to support .wav - it works in neither of them. I tried to replace the `<audio>` element with a [react-audio-player](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-audio-player), a react-player and a [react-sound](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-sound-dkadrios) element - none of them works.
When I open the URL, the sound is downloaded as an attachment.

```js
    render() {

        const wavUrl = config.fileServer+this.props.values.id+".wav";

        return (
            <audio controls>
                <source src={wavUrl} type="audio/wav" />
                Your browser does not support the audio element.
            </audio>
        );
    }
```

I expect to see an audio controller that starts playing the sound when I press play. Instead, I see an audio controller that does nothing when I press play, and that claims that the audio file is 0 seconds long. I checked the URL - it is correct if I past it as URL in my browser directly.

Comment: How did you create the wav file?

Comment: Try using this file and see if it works http://freewavesamples.com/files/Kawai-K11-CleanGtr-C3.wav

Comment: @KitangaNday I did not create it, it just lies on this file server. If I download it and play it outside a browser, it also works fine.

Comment: Is it possible for me to see this file?

Comment: It does not work with that file either unfortunately

Comment: I am not allowed to share it, sorry

Comment: Are you using create-react-app?

Comment: I am not sure if the app was created with create-react-app, do you know how to find this out?

Comment: Check the package.json file and see if there's any `react-scripts` word

Comment: @nielsrolf - check post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39787533/play-sound-in-react-js

Comment: And that worked? Wow xD

Comment: `react-scripts` is there. I will also try @jank 's suggestion now

Comment: I'll be here waiting to see if this works

Comment: @jank thanks for the suggestions, but I cannot really apply this since I am not dealing with relative file paths (also from the question I can't tell what this `Audio` class is)

Comment: Pretty much Audio === <audio></audio>. Think of it like how we can create an Image object using `Image` and this is the same as having/creating an `img` element

Answer (score 3):

If you are using `create-react-app` you have to import the audio file.

```
import wavUrl from './path/to/file';

// ... rest of code here
```

Comment: The url is created dynamically from the props of the rendering component, so this is also not possible for me. By the way, thanks a lot for your effort!

Comment: Where are the files stored. in your src folder or the public folder? (Oh, and pleasure)

Comment: The .wav file is stored on a static file server

Comment: OK, go to your webpage in browser and refresh the page.

Comment: Tell me what you see i the browser's console

Comment: I just see some unrelated 'someVar was declared but never used'. I can use .flac files instead, with them it works easily, because of time constraints I will go with this solution for now. If you have more suggestions, I will try them out in the evening

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned Kitanga, you can use import to load files from public (instead of full URL access), example:

```
import somefile from '../public/assets/mp3/test1.mp3'
```

then

```
Play extends Component {
...
}

render(
  <Play file=somefile>
)
```

But if you found webpack error message at start: "You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type..." then seems you need to load appropriate extension npm package to read it and configure webpack.config.js, example:

```
 ...
 module: {
   rules: [
     {
       test: /\.mp3$/,
       loader: "file-loader"
     },
     ...
   ]
   ...
 ...
```

if "file-loader" not installed then use example:

```
 npm install --save file-loader
```

Comment: To add onto this, I got it working after going to 'index.d.ts' and adding `declare module '*.wav';` to get rid of the error. I'm using wav files, so if you are using mp3, just replace with mp3.